# Can't drag over GoogleMaps when using CoordinatorLayout

Tags: google-maps, xamarin.android, mapbox

When I add too many floating action menus or floating action buttons in a CoordinatorLayout over a Google Map, the drag doesn't work well anymore. I'm only able to drag the map if I touch on the top right corner of the map.

I'm using Mapbox API but the behavior is the same as Google Maps API.

My layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
  <!-- MAP -->
  <com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    app:access_token="TOKEN" />
<!-- TIME -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnExamTime"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_button_info_exam"
        android:text="00:00"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:clickable="false" />
<!-- INFO -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnExamInfo"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_button_info_exam"
        android:text="Aula 5 | Paul Walker"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:clickable="false"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/btnExamTime"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="right" />
<!-- MENU -->
    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
        android:id="@+id/fab_exam_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin_right"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin_bottom"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:menu_icon="@drawable/icon_fab_exam"
        app:menu_animationDelayPerItem="0"
        app:menu_shadowColor="#999"
        app:menu_colorNormal="#272B35"
        app:menu_colorPressed="@color/accent"
        app:menu_colorRipple="#272B35"
        app:menu_labels_textSize="20sp">
    <!-- START EXAM -->
        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_start_exam"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_fab_start_exam"
            app:fab_colorNormal="@color/green_spring"
            app:fab_colorPressed="@color/accent"
            app:fab_size="mini"
            app:fab_label="Iniciar aula" />
    <!-- END EXAM -->
        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_end_exam"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_fab_end_exam"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:fab_colorNormal="@color/red_low"
            app:fab_colorPressed="@color/accent"
            app:fab_size="mini"
            app:fab_label="Finalizar aula" />
    <!-- REGISTERED INFO -->
        <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_registered_violations"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_fab_check"
            app:fab_colorNormal="#272B35"
            app:fab_colorPressed="@color/accent"
            app:fab_size="mini"
            app:fab_label="Infrações registradas" />
    </com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>
<!-- CONTENT -->
    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_exam_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginRight="110dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin_bottom"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_fab_exam_content"
        app:fab_size="normal"
        app:fab_shadowColor="#999"
        app:fab_colorNormal="#272B35"
        app:fab_colorPressed="@color/accent"
        app:fab_colorRipple="#61646E"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/fab_exam_menu"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" />
<!-- MENU  -->
    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
        android:id="@+id/fab_conduct_violation_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginRight="205dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin_bottom"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:menu_icon="@drawable/icon_fab_violation_conduct"
        app:menu_animationDelayPerItem="0"
        app:menu_shadowColor="#999"
        app:menu_colorNormal="#272B35"
        app:menu_colorPressed="@color/accent"
        app:menu_colorRipple="#272B35"
        app:menu_labels_textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/fab_exam_menu"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" />
<!-- MENU  -->
    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
        android:id="@+id/fab_light_violation_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginRight="300dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin_bottom"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:menu_icon="@drawable/icon_fab_violation_light"
        app:menu_animationDelayPerItem="0"
        app:menu_shadowColor="#999"
        app:menu_colorNormal="#272B35"
        app:menu_colorPressed="@color/accent"
        app:menu_colorRipple="#272B35"
        app:menu_labels_textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/fab_exam_menu"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" />
<!-- MENU  -->
    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
        android:id="@+id/fab_medium_violation_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginRight="395dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin_bottom"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:menu_icon="@drawable/icon_fab_violation_medium"
        app:menu_animationDelayPerItem="0"
        app:menu_shadowColor="#999"
        app:menu_colorNormal="#272B35"
        app:menu_colorPressed="@color/accent"
        app:menu_colorRipple="#272B35"
        app:menu_labels_textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/fab_exam_menu"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" />
<!-- MENU  -->
    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
        android:id="@+id/fab_high_violation_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginRight="490dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin_bottom"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:menu_icon="@drawable/icon_fab_violation_high"
        app:menu_animationDelayPerItem="0"
        app:menu_shadowColor="#999"
        app:menu_colorNormal="#272B35"
        app:menu_colorPressed="@color/accent"
        app:menu_colorRipple="#272B35"
        app:menu_labels_textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/fab_exam_menu"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" />
<!-- MENU  -->
    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
        android:id="@+id/fab_danger_violation_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginRight="585dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin_bottom"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:menu_icon="@drawable/icon_fab_violation_danger"
        app:menu_animationDelayPerItem="0"
        app:menu_shadowColor="#999"
        app:menu_colorNormal="#272B35"
        app:menu_colorPressed="@color/accent"
        app:menu_colorRipple="#272B35"
        app:menu_labels_textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/fab_exam_menu"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" />
```

And a screen example of how it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just discovered what causes that behavior.

I have about 6 items inside the floating action menus. For some reason the area that the items (floating action buttons) and its labels covers I can't touch. It's like the menu creates an invisible panel that stays above the map.

My solution was remove the items of the menus. After that the drag started to work well again.